# imagelist set imagesize doesn't resize subsequently added images

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In a function to resize the displayed images in `CurrentImages`, the images, all of a sudden and only in this production version, not in a previous test version, don't seem to scale.

Instead they are clipped.

```
private void ResizeCurrentImages(double zoom)
{
    foreach (Image image in this.CurrentImages.Images)
    {
        image.Dispose();
    }

    this.CurrentImages.Images.Clear();
    this.CurrentImages.ImageSize = new Size((int)Math.Floor(this.MAX_WIDTH * zoom), (int)Math.Floor(this.MAX_HEIGHT * zoom));    

    foreach (Image image in this.OriginalImages.Images)
    {
        this.CurrentImages.Images.Add(image);
    }
}
```

where `MAX_WIDTH = 161` and `MAX_HEIGHT = 256`.

According to MSDN documentation, I'm following the right steps, first setting the new imagesize, and then adding the images.

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error was somewhere else in the code. There is another section changing the images, and it created a Bitmap using an original size, instead of the zoomed size.